# What is this feature on a Piaggio P.180?

Tags: aircraft-design, wing, feature-identification

[image]
([wikimedia.org](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Piaggio_P.180_Avanti_Foxair_hl.jpg))

What is this feature on a [Piaggio P.180](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piaggio_P.180_Avanti)?

I believe it's called a dolphin tail, but why is it exactly there and what is it for and why don't all airplanes have this?

Comment: It's called a strake, [this question](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/11808/62) explains what they're for and how they work

Comment: My question is different because I have a few other questions that I want answered instead of just one question.

Comment: I don't want to be difficult, but I don't see anything in this question that isn't answered in the other one: it tells you what strakes are, why they're positioned at the tail, and which types of planes often need them. If you're sure that your question is different, I suggest that you edit to give some more information about exactly what isn't answered in the other one.

Comment: `why can't all airplanes have this` - who said that they can't?  Whether they are required or not or would improve performance is another matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The airfoils shown are delta fins.  They provide lateral stability during higher speed flight.  It helps to reduce dutch rolling tendencies and to prevent deep stall characteristics.

So much so that on the Learjets I fly, there is no need for an operable yaw damper.  There is also no stick pusher or stick puller system.  Older Learjets without delta fins are required to have those two systems installed.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piaggio_P.180_Avanti